# Sorting out redundant text from screen scraper application

Tags: string, sequence, text-processing

You are writing a screen scraper application monitoring a text-only chat window. Text is added at the bottom of the window.

The application takes screenshot of the chat window. If a change has occurred since last screenshot (new_screenshot != old_screenshot), the screenshot is saved.

After X time, all images are merged to one image, where the oldest image is on the top. This large image is send to a server for OCR, and a string of text is returned.

**Challenge:** Sort out redundant text.

Example: Chat window is 5 lines high and is initially empty. The solution must work with empty and not-empty initial chat window. More than one line can be added at each screenshot.

**Input to algorithm:**

1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
2 consectetur adipiscing elit
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
2 consectetur adipiscing elit
3 Mauris porttitor enim sed tincidunt interdum.
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
2 consectetur adipiscing elit
3 Mauris porttitor enim sed tincidunt interdum.
4 Morbi elementum erat nec nulla auctor, eget porta odio aliquet.
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
2 consectetur adipiscing elit
3 Mauris porttitor enim sed tincidunt interdum.
4 Morbi elementum erat nec nulla auctor, eget porta odio aliquet.
5 Nam aliquet velit vel elementum tristique.
2 consectetur adipiscing elit 
3 Mauris porttitor enim sed tincidunt interdum. 
4 Morbi elementum erat nec nulla auctor, eget porta odio aliquet. 
5 Nam aliquet velit vel elementum tristique. 
6 Donec ac tincidunt urna. 
3 Mauris porttitor enim sed tincidunt interdum.
4 Morbi elementum erat nec nulla auctor, eget porta odio aliquet.
5 Nam aliquet velit vel elementum tristique.
6 Donec ac tincidunt urna.
7 Proin pretium, metus non porttitor lobortis, tortor sem rhoncus urna
4 Morbi elementum erat nec nulla auctor, eget porta odio aliquet.
5 Nam aliquet velit vel elementum tristique.
6 Donec ac tincidunt urna.
7 Proin pretium, metus non porttitor lobortis, tortor sem rhoncus urna
8 quis finibus leo lorem sed lacus.
5 Nam aliquet velit vel elementum tristique.
6 Donec ac tincidunt urna.
7 Proin pretium, metus non porttitor lobortis, tortor sem rhoncus urna
8 quis finibus leo lorem sed lacus.
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

**Expected result:**

1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
2 consectetur adipiscing elit 
 
3 Mauris porttitor enim sed tincidunt interdum. 
4 Morbi elementum erat nec nulla auctor, eget porta odio aliquet. 
5 Nam aliquet velit vel elementum tristique. 
6 Donec ac tincidunt urna. 
7 Proin pretium, metus non porttitor lobortis, tortor sem rhoncus urna 
8 quis finibus leo lorem sed lacus. 
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

**UPDATE:** I forgot an important detail in the original challenge: The same line can come multiple times, **but never two times in a row** so just deduplicating is not enough.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This site is a language-agnostic challenge site, it's not like StackOverflow. I've tried to edit your question to stay on topic. If you are looking for a solution to a problem you cannot solve, this may not be the site for you.

Comment: Hi Vingtoft, and welcome to PPCG!  As it stands, this question would likely be a better fit for StackOverflow.  That said, if you add a win condition (usually [tag:code-golf]), this could make for a good challenge.  In the future, we also recommend running questions through the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/48543) before posting here.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the violation of community guidelines. Feel free to delete my challenge.

Comment: @Vingtoft No worries.  I hope we'll see you again for future challenges.  Incidentally, what you're looking for is probably `sorted(set(text.split('\n')))`.

Comment: Em, the challenge looks ok to me...

Comment: Am I missing something or is this just split on newlines and deduplicate?

Comment: @Shaggy: I have updated my question. One line can appear multiple times (but never two times in a row), so just deduplicating would not be enough. Sorry for the inadequate initial description.

Comment: What is the input? The height and the merged screenshot?

Comment: Also, in the example, the first and second lines are identical. What do you mean by saying that the same line can't come twice in a row?

Comment: The same line will never come twice in a row in "expected result", but it might occur in input. Yes, window height is known and can be used as input.

Comment: so... the input in your example input comprises of 7 blocks (screens) of 5 lines of text? and you are logging the additions from one screen to the other? and the line 1 is repeated because it appears in [5,6,7,8,1]  but not in [4,5,6,7,8] (previous screen) ?

Comment: so the output is the result of seven comparisons which in sequence add: [1,2] [3,4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [1 ?]

Comment: Hi and welcome to PPCG.  Generally it is frowned upon to change the question after answers have been given, especially if it invalidates existing answers.  I just voted to close due to the question now being unclear. I'll delete my own answer for now, until I can understand exactly what is being asked.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I understand, apologies, this is my first question on this site.

Comment: 1. you should post challenges in the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active#tab-top) before posting on main site. 2. all challenges must have an **objective winning criteria** (see [help/on-topic]) . 3. you should absolutely avoid writing posts on this site like help request -- it's a **challenge**, not a question, not a task, not an assignment. 4. see [When is EDIT/UPDATE appropriate in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639) 5. See formatting help, you should format data as code.

Comment: @Stephen [On editing somebody else's off-topic question to make it on-topic without the owner's word - Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Meta Stack Exchange](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14838/69850) Instead, tell OP how to edit the post *in the comment section*.

Answer (score 0):

## Japt `-R`, 11 bytes

This passes the test case but the spec still isn't clear enough

```
·ò¨ mÌò¦ mg
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=t/KoIG3M8qYgbWc=&input=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)